# Create dynamic modal but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to trigger the modal but it doesn't work at all, 
I've got my button and I used jquery to create a dynamic modal its not work if anyone have a idea.

```js
 
  
  $("#myModal").click(function() {
   
  
  var MysModel = ' <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">\
 <div id="page-dialog" class="modal-dialog">\
\
  <!-- Modal content-->\
  <div class="modal-content">\
   <div class="modal-header">\
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>\
    <h3 class="title-modal">tyu</h3>\
   </div>\
   \
   <div id="page-content" class="modal-body">\
    <p>ghuihuighgoghggog</p>\
   </div>\
   <div class="modal-footer">\
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>\
   </div>\
  </div>\
\
 </div>\
</div>'
```

```html
<button class="addweb" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Website</button>


<div id="sectionModal"></div>
```

Comment: Change id "sectionModal" from <div id="sectionModal"></div> to "myModal".

Comment: Are you repeating the `myModal` id?  Cause you have a click binding for it and it's the id of the div inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/38960/)**.

You don't need to attach any event, all what you want is appending the modal to the `sectionModal` div like :

```
$('#sectionModal').append(MysModel);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var MysModel = ' <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">\
 <div id="page-dialog" class="modal-dialog">\
  <!-- Modal content-->\
  <div class="modal-content">\
   <div class="modal-header">\
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>\
    <h3 class="title-modal">tyu</h3>\
   </div>\
   \
   <div id="page-content" class="modal-body">\
    <p>ghuihuighgoghggog</p>\
   </div>\
   <div class="modal-footer">\
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>\
   </div>\
  </div>\
 </div>\
</div>';

$('#sectionModal').append(MysModel);

$('#open-modal').on('click', function(){
    $('#myModal').modal();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="addweb" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Website</button>

<button type="button" id="open-modal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="sectionModal"></div>
```

Comment: Zakaria Acharki  how do I trigger the modal with function click